# Running python script in background in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, scheduler

I am running a python in Windows 10 Command prompt. After the system is kept idle the script stop working. The system also had sleep mode turned off. I need to press "enter" key to make script working again. I tried windows scheduler, however it shows CMD pop up everytime script is executed. Please suggest solution to run the script without any human intervention. I am running the script in cmd with 'schedule' module for running after specific interval.

Comment: For the original problem, ensure that the console isn't accidentally in select mode, which changes the window title to start with "Select". This can happen accidentally with a single click on the window if quick-edit mode is enabled in the console. In select mode, reading from and writing to the console is blocked, which can block the execution of a script if it's not designed with multithreading to separate UI from processing.

Comment: For the task scheduler issue, that's a console window, which gets created automatically for programs that are flagged to require a console session. It has nothing to do with cmd.exe, and it's not a "CMD pop up". If you don't need a console session with standard I/O in a console window, run the script with "pythonw.exe" instead of "python.exe".